# How to convert a string into LocalDate formate?

Tags: java, spring, date

I am using java 1.8 and using [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

I am getting date from my bean as String format in the form `dd/MM/YYYY`

> 07/01/2017

.
And I want the same formate When converted to localDate.

The requirement is to store it in a database column with datatype as date.

Comment: Which database you are Using ?

Comment: I am using oracle DB

Comment: You need to understand that objects of type `LocalDate` don't have a format. Its method `toString()` uses a fixed format corresponding to pattern uuuu-MM-dd. If you want to configure your custom format then you have to set up your own formatter object which is independent from the objects to be formatted. In short: value object is not format object.